# Concat a specific time, onto a date in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report where a user will choose a date range (2 dropdown). Inside the stored procedure I would like to use this date as passed, but append a specific time on the end of it.

I've been googling for a while and tried many things. But am not an expert and can't seem to land on a working solution

CURRENT CODE:

In my stored procedure, I capture the dates passed in:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_JollySDKSkillChange]
@in_startdate datetime,
@in_enddate datetime
```

Then in the where clause ....

```
where  dbo.JollySDKSkillChange.AddedDate between @in_startdate and @in_enddate
```

I need not only the date, but the start date should include 00:00:00 and the end date should include 23:59:59

How can I concatenate the specific times, onto the end of the date that is passed ?

At the moment, I do not get any results. But executing the stored procedure with a date and time together for each ... it provides the expected results.

Comment: Why are your parameters defined as datetime and not date? Don't encourage misunderstanding and mistaken assumptions.

Comment: And don't use a fixed, inclusive upper boundary. 23:59:59 is NOT the maximum value possible for a datetime. You ignore the milliseconds - which you might think is safe but life has a habit of finding these assumptions and breaking them.

Comment: Exhaustive detail in [Tibor's discussion of datetime](https://karaszi.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-the-datetime-datatypes). Using dates (not datetimes), your queries are as simple as "select ... where <col> >= at_startdate and <col> < dateadd(day, 1, enddate)". NB - can't use at sign in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the values after you receive them inside the stored procedure. Your @in_startdate should already be 00:00:00 because you've defined it as datetime, even if you only sent in a date.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_JollySDKSkillChange]
     @in_startdate datetime,
     @in_enddate datetime
AS BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SET @in_enddate = DATEADD(second,-1,dateadd(day,1,@in_enddate))

--Test values here
SELECT @in_startdate, @in_enddate

...

END
```

Comment: Thank you @FembotDBA . I can execute the Sp with just a date, and get the results ... however when running my SSRS report ... I'm not getting results. ;( So working through the .rdl file line by line to see if I'm missing anything obvious. I'm kinda stumped

Comment: This resolved the original issue. Now I have a specific SSRS issue. Thanks again